# WebTest / LoadTest in Release Management

Tags: azure-devops, load-testing, webtest

I build a simple webtest in Visual Studio:

[image]

As PandoraBox variable I filled in the URl of our development environment. When doing a release via release management to this environment I run this test and also as load test. So far so good.

Today we added a demo environment and after deploy I want use this test again; just with a different value for PandoraBox.

I used a test task in VSTS and tried to override the url; but so far no luck. Someone experiences with this?

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I fixed it by making a powershell script that edits the .webtest (which is just an xml file)